# Why does the text-decoration of a <div> inside an <a> not override its parent?

Tags: html, css

This is more of a theoretical question that I'm struggling to get my head around. I have an `<a>` with a `<div>` inside of it.

As far as I understood it, the `<div>` should initially inherit its `text-decoration` from its parent `<a>` and therefore be, by default, `underline`. As expected the content inside the `<div>` is underlined.

But then I set the `text-decoration` of the `<div>` to `none`, and I would expect this to then override the inheritance from the parent and cause the content inside of the `<div>` not to be underlined any more. This is not the case though, and it remains underlined.

I know that I can simply set the `text-decoration` of the parent `<a>` to `none`, but I am struggling to understand the reason why what I am doing doesn't work.

```css
div {
  text-decoration: none
}
```

```html
<a href="#">
  <div>This text is still underlined</div>
</a>
```